# Django: ManyToManyField related name not working

Tags: django, django-related-manager

Im trying to output all the events that a member is one of the sponsors and speakers of that event. Using `member.event_set.all` works fine for members that were event speakers. But if I use `member.msponsor_set.all` for members that were event sponsors nothing is returned.

Here is my event model...

```
class Event(models.Model):
    member_speaker = models.ManyToManyField(Member)
    member_sponsor = models.ManyToManyField(Member, related_name='msponsor')
```

Comment: Can you post the whole Event model?

Comment: Please share the whole event model as well as the Member model

Comment: By setting `related_name` you’re replacing the default `_set` conventions for the `RelatedManager` you have to do this in this case since both relationships are pointing to the same model. A better naming would have been `related_name=sponsored_events` so the related query would read `member.sponsored_events.all()` (note it’s plural and it described the model on which it’s defined not the model to which the field refers to).

Comment: Do you really mean that the member has to be a sponsor *and* a speaker?

Comment: followed the suggestion of @dirkgroten and boom it worked. Thanks man, I should have named it better xD

Answer (score 2):

Don't know what the set is used for but doing

```
member.msponsor.all()
```

can give you all the events data related to that sponsor.

Comment: I have tried that solution but nothing is returned, but thanks man.